# How to set lubuntu to lock the screen after idle?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

The system is ubuntu 14.04 , lubuntu desktop. How do i set it to lock the screen with password after idle?

Answer (score 1):

If you use xscreensaver, as we do, tick the box at the bottom of this screen:

[image]

Otherwise, set your desired options on this screen:

[image]

Comment: XScreenSaver is awesome!

Comment: i tried with xscreensaver but didn't automatically lock, and i cant find  power management settings nor system settings. i giving up. thanks